# ChoiceBox Background Colour Wont Change With Certain Colours

Tags: java, javafx

For some reason the colour of the background won't change for certain colours. It doesn't change for "Yellow" or "Pink". The only reason I could think of is that those are AWT colours and it is using that instead of JavaFX colours but i am not sure why the others wouldn't do that.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OHPN.jpg) is a picture of the issue and the intended result

This is my code for the colour changing of the ChoiceBox:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import java.io.InputStream;

    public class Clock extends Application {

        public Text text;

            @Override 
            public void start(Stage stage) {

                    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE,MMM d yyyy - h:mm:ss a");
                    Date date = new Date();
                    String stringDate = df.format(date);

                    text = new Text(10, 60, stringDate);
                    Font font = null;

                    InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/DIGITALDREAMFAT.ttf");

                    try {
                    font = Font.loadFont(input, 30); 
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    text.setFont(font);
                    text.setFill(Color.RED);


            Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                    Date update = new Date();
                    String stringNewDate = df.format(update);
                    text.setText(stringNewDate);
                    }
            }), new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1)));

            timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
            timeline.play();

                    ChoiceBox colorChoice = new ChoiceBox(FXCollections.observableArrayList("Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Pink", "Grey", "Black", "White"));

                    colorChoice.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
                        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                            if (colorChoice.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Red")) {
                            colorChoice.setStyle("-fx-base: red");
                            text.setFill(Color.RED);
                            } else if (colorChoice.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Blue")) {
                            colorChoice.setStyle("-fx-base: blue");
                            text.setFill(Color.BLUE);
                            } else if (colorChoice.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Green")) {
                            colorChoice.setStyle("-fx-base: green");
                            text.setFill(Color.GREEN);
                            } else if (colorChoice.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Grey")) {
                            colorChoice.setStyle("-fx-base: grey");
                            text.setFill(Color.GREY);
                            } else if (colorChoice.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString().equals("White")) {
                            colorChoice.setStyle("-fx-base: white");
                            text.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                            } else if (colorChoice.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Black")) {
                            colorChoice.setStyle("-fx-base: black");
                            text.setFill(Color.BLACK);
                            } else if (colorChoice.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Yellow")) {
                            colorChoice.setStyle("-fx-base: yellow");
                            text.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
                            } else if (colorChoice.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Pink")) {
                            colorChoice.setStyle("-fx-base: pink");
                            text.setFill(Color.PINK);
                            } else {
                            colorChoice.setStyle("-fx-base: red");
                            text.setFill(Color.RED);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    HBox hbox = new HBox(colorChoice);
                    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(text, hbox));


                    hbox.setSpacing(10);

                    colorChoice.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Select Text Colour"));
                    colorChoice.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();


                    scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

                    stage.setScene(scene);
                    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
                    stage.setX(0);
                    stage.setY(0);
                    stage.setWidth(710);
                    stage.setHeight(80);
                    stage.show(); 
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                    launch(args);
            }
    }
```

Comment: What kind of framework are you using? Not GWT, if I understood things correctly... Please add the full classnames for ChoiceBox and whatever class 'text' is so that we have a chance at helping you!

Comment: Why don't you use a single loop and check the text as String for each item and apply the color according to the text, instead of using the conditions ? exemple `"-fx-text-fill:"+StringColor+";"`

Comment: @subrunner I edited it with the whole code. Sorry bout that

Comment: @BoHalim I tried that but it didn't recognize it properly and didn't change the colour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default color of the drop-down menu is the looked-up color `-fx-control-inner-background`: this in turn defaults to a very light version of `-fx-base` (it is 80% lighter than `-fx-base`). Thus if you start with a light color for `-fx-base`, such as yellow, it will be effectively completely lightened to near-white. If you replace `-fx-control-inner-background` for the choice box, you will get the desired effect.

Note you can get rid of the ridiculous `if-else` construct, since the selected item in the choice box contains all the information you need.

```
    ChoiceBox<String> colorChoice = new ChoiceBox<>(
            FXCollections.observableArrayList("Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Pink", "Grey", "Black", "White"));

    colorChoice.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {

            String choice = colorChoice.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() ;
            if (choice != null) {
                String color = choice.toLowerCase();
                colorChoice.setStyle("-fx-base: "+color+"; -fx-control-inner-background: -fx-base ;");
                text.setFill(Color.web(color));
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is there a way I can still make the others 80% lighter and make yellow only a little lighter (I will test values)?

Comment: I can't see an easy way to do that. Probably you would make the items in the choice box a user-defined class encapsulating two colors and a display string, one color for `-fx-base` and one for `-fx-control-inner-basckground`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you're listening to the control itself and not the items, and the change will not take place, it always passes by the else condition, so when you click on the control it will choose the color by default red (no item is selected) so if you want to change the color of the ChoiceBox depeding on the selected item use this :

```
cb.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {

            cb.setStyle("-fx-base:" + newValue.toLowerCase() + ";");


        }
    });
```

**Note:** This changes the control according to the selected item and not the item itself, and I would be surprised if there was a method that manages the  cell property !

Good luck !